# Adding arguments in Jython PythonInterpreter to the "execfile" function

Tags: java, python, jython

I have a python script that I would like to execute in Java with Jython.
The Python script accepts 2 arguments. How can I add arguments to the script?

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.execfile("C:/path/to/file/__main__.py");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`execfile` executes the script in the local namespace. You could simply assign the value to `sys.argv` in a prior call to `exec`:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec(
    "import sys\n"
    +"sys.argv = ['Foo', 'Bar']");
interpreter.execfile("J:/test.py");
```

Where the script is:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

prints:

```
['Foo', 'Bar']
```

---

I looked into the question of your comment, and it looks like you would need to set `python.path` in a `Properties` object that you then pass to [`PythonInterpreter.initialize`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#initialize(java.util.Properties,%20java.util.Properties,%20java.lang.String[])). You could also use this to pass the arguments:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("python.path", "J:/WS/jython"); // Sets the module path

PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), p, new String[]{ "Foo", "Bar" });

PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.execfile("J:/WS/jython/main.py");
```

Comment: Thanks @Jorn Vernee If my Python script consts of several files, then do I need to import them somehow?

Comment: Thank you @Jorn for the help!